# How to compare the schema of two datasets with Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have two Datasets (dsFile and dsTable) with the following schema :

dsFile :

```
dsFile
  |-- A: string (nullable = true)
  |-- B: string (nullable = true)
  |-- C: string (nullable = true)
```

dsTable :

```
dsTable
  |-- A: string (nullable = true)
  |-- B: string (nullable = true)
  |-- C: string (nullable = true)
  |-- D: string (nullable = true)
  |-- E: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to find the column differences between this two datasets ? And build a new dsFile dataset with the differences :

dsFileNew :

```
dsFileNew
  |-- A: string (nullable = true)
  |-- B: string (nullable = true)
  |-- C: string (nullable = true)
  |-- D: string (nullable = true) // column of dsTable
  |-- E: string (nullable = true) // column of dsTable
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862974/schema-comparison-of-two-dataframes-in-scala?

Comment: How do you want to join `dsFile` and `dsTable`? On which column?