# How to detect change in CSV file schema in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

If there is change in schema in my incoming CSV file, how can we handle this in spark?

Suppose on Day-1,
I got a csv file with schema and data as below,

```
FirstName LastName Age
Sagar     Patro    26
Akash     Nayak    22
Amar      Kumar    18
```

And on Day 10,
My incoming CSV file schema got changes, as below

```
FirstName LastName Mobile     Age 
Sagar     Patro    8984159475 26  
Akash     Nayak    9040988503 22  
Amar      Kumar    9337856871 18
```

**My Requirement No-1,**

I want to know, if there is any change in Schema to my incoming CSV file.

**My Requirement No-2,**

I want to ignore those new added columns and continue with my earlier schema i.e. Day-1 schema data.

**My Requirement No-3,**

I also want to add the new schema automatically if there is change in schema to my incoming csv data i.e. Day-10 Schema

Comment: you need to find the differences between the schemas, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862974/schema-comparison-of-two-dataframes-in-scala) you can find an extensive discussion about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

object SchemaDiff {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Just because its a simple CSV not considering column data type changes
    val df1 : DataFrame = null // Dataframe for yesterday's data
    val df2 : DataFrame = null // Dataframe for today's data
    val deltaColumnNames = df2.columns.diff(df1.columns)
    val ignoreSchemaChange = true
    if(!deltaColumnNames.isEmpty) {
      println("Schema change")
    }
    val resultDf = if(ignoreSchemaChange) {
      df2.toDF(df1.columns: _*) // Maintain yesterday's schema
    } else {
      df2  // Use updated schema
    }

  }
}
```